# Visual Studio 2017 has no Business Intelligence to create SSIS package

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis

I installed  Visual Studio 2017 and using this link [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teJxX.jpg)

I installed SSDT for visual studio 2017 also I installed Data-Tier Application Framework (DacFx) 17.4 (64bit and 32 bit) which is used by VS2017.as shown in first pic its show SQL Server Data Tools is installed on VS2017 [image]

but when I try to create new SSIS project I dont see Business Intelligence as shown in the pic2[image]

Your help is appreciated

Comment: You are showing C# templates, have you checked SqlServer option?

Comment: yeah, SQL server has only SWL Server Database Project @McNets

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and back on again?

Comment: if u mean shutting down VS and again starting, yes I did, even I rebooted my OS :D @dfundako

Comment: Look this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46700769/3270427

Comment: I tried this before, what i explained I have done so far was based on this but still not showing @McNets

Answer (score 2):

ok here is the solution,
what i did is i uninstall SSDT, again tried to instal SSDt but this time I selected "Visual Studio Professional 2017" and only "Sql Server Integration Service" as shown in pic1 [image]

and now I have Business Intelligence template when I want to create new project as shown in pic2[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, So install the SSIS first and then SSRS and then SSAS will install everything and solve the issue.