# Adding SSIS capability to Visual Studio Enterprise 2017

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

Can I add SSIS capability to Visual Studio Enterprise 2017?

How do I add SSIS capability to Visual Studio Enterprise 2017?

I've looked in "Visual Studio Installer" at the "Workloads" options and also the "Individual Components" options .. but I can't see SSIS listed ?

Maybe I need a different version of Visual Studio for SSIS work?

Comment: I spotted similar discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43689193/visual-studio-2017-does-not-have-business-intelligence-integration-services-proj   but any new comments here very welcome !

Comment: Page  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-vs-2017-standalone-installer   has link for download Download SSDT for Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.2)    in the middle of the article ..  I'm giving this a try ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft page here has answer to this question.

- [Download and install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-vs-2017-standalone-installer)

i.e. this Microsoft article has a link for "Download SSDT for Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.2)" in the middle of this article which can be used.

The "Visual Studio Installer" tool from Start menu wasn't so useful for adding this capability (for me).